# Results from search in Magento 2 relevance not correct

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, search, catalogsearch, magento2.3.3

I've the problem that the results from an search query on frontend are in the wrong relevance. It is on an live webshop. For example, when i search 'Philips' or 'Grohe', the first product is in both search-queries always 'Creative SB Tactic 360 Sigma Headset'.

As you can see in the title, there is no 'Philips' in the productname, but it is always the first product.

My search attributes are [image: attribute codes - searchable]

Comment: But that search done on another fields as well

Comment: I dont understand you’re message, how do you mean another fields?